# Lebesgue point and regularity of functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

A known theorem says that for $f \in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, almost every point is a Lebesgue point.

I know too a theorem saying that for $f \in W_{loc}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ , every point is a Lebesgue point outside a set of zero p-capacity and for a continous fonction, every point is a Lebesgue point.

My question is: is there some kind of reciprocical to these theorems? For example, can I say that $f$ belongs to a certain space if every point is a Lebesgue point for $f$?

Comment: If *every* point is a Lebesgue point, then, every point has a neighborhood over which $f$ is integrable, so $f\in L^1_{loc}$. Interestingly enough, you can say more, for instance, you have the weak intermediate value property for such functions because for any non-trivial measurable set, you can find a point that sees both the set and its complement at arbitrarily small scales. However, such functions may have very severe discontinuities. So the answer is "Yes, they belong to a certain linear space but the only way to describe that space is by its defining property or a reformulation thereof".

Comment: Thank you, it's very interesting. Would you have any reference for this "weak intermediate value property" for example?

Comment: Maybe also of interest here: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Approximate_continuity A lot of work has been done on this.